# How to make a lighweight webhook handler with Jetty? (currently works*, but service sending request says it doesn't)

Tags: java, http, jetty, wireshark

**Background**

To receive data from a specific service, I am limited to a few options, the quickest being WebSocket. I decided I could write a lightweight application specifically to move data from this into another service, and started with something based off with something based around [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html), and quickly got it working so I could receive post requests. All my testing with `curl` seemed to indicate it worked fine and when actual data came from the service sending the requests, the data came in just fine, but the application sending it said that the request failed.
. . . So I decided to scrap that project and start over with Jetty. Again, I got this working rather quickly, all the tests with `curl` seemed fine, and I could in-fact read data from the real service sending requests, but again, the service would indicate that the content was not properly received (even though it was). Since I had the same problem twice, I decided to stick with this implementation and investigate further.

**Problem/question**

How can I properly write a handler for webhooks in Jetty? *or*
What could cause the service to say that the request did not go through?

**Things I think are relevant to the issue:**

- I keep getting this exception, and can't find out how to fix it. I really don't know if this is the issue.

  ```
  java.io.IOException: Unconsumed content
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContentProducer.consumeAll(AsyncContentProducer.java:168)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingContentProducer.consumeAll(BlockingContentProducer.java:85)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.consumeAll(HttpInput.java:155)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onCompleted(HttpConnection.java:439)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.onCompleted(HttpChannel.java:872)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:386)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:319)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SocketChannelEndPoint$1.run(SocketChannelEndPoint.java:101)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:894)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1038)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
  ```
- Upon inspecting in wireshark I saw this: [[link to wireshark pic where everything looks good until the way end]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Jyj.png)

Hopefully this isn't too rambley, I know its not exactly a clear or specific 'question'...

Comment: Make sure you read the content you are sent.  It is not appropriate to handle the request and not read the request body content.  You violate the HTTP connection persistence rules doing that.

Comment: I am reading through `request.getInputStream().readAllBytes()` and closing the stream at the end.

Comment: Your stacktrace is telling you that you haven't read all of the content.  So either you have a bad `Content-Length` that doesn't match what has actually been sent, or you haven't actually read all of the bytes like you think you have.

Comment: If you feel this might be a bug in Jetty, and you have a reproduction case you can share, file an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues (we can help you, even if it's just a question and some simple review of your efforts)

Comment: I'll post it as a question, I think the likelihood of me finding a legitimate bug like this in the first 20 minutes of using Jetty to be... unlikely. I'd guess I'm just doing something wrong considering I'm fairly new to this. Anyway, I created [this issue / question](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/6614)